# Is this group of matrices a $p$-group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory

Let $R$ be a discrete valuation ring with the maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}=(\pi)$ and residue field $k$ of positive characteristic $p$. Now consider $\mathrm{M}_n(\pi^iR/\pi^{i+1}R)$, $n\times n$ matrices with entries in $\pi^iR/\pi^{i+1}R$.

Is it true that $\mathrm{Id} + \mathrm{M}_n(\pi^iR/\pi^{i+1}R)$ is a $p$-group?

Comment: it is correct. Then $(Id + A)(Id+A)= Id + 2A$ and maybe this can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A\in M_n(\pi^iR/\pi^{i+1}R)$. Then $A^2=0$ since $ab=0$ for $a,b\in\pi^iR/\pi^{i+1}R$.

Since $p(R/\pi R)=0$ it follows $pR\subseteq\pi R$ hence $p\pi^iR\subseteq\pi^{i+1}R$, that is, $p(\pi^iR/\pi^{i+1}R)=0$. Therefore $pA=0$.

We then have $(I+A)^p=\sum_{i=0}^p{p\choose i}A^i=I+pA=I$.